# Is it same distance Equator & Prime Meridian?

Tags: earth

i just want to ask in earth what  the difference between Equator & Prime Meridian & also want to know is it same distance Equator & Prime Meridian?

[image]

Comment: You mean length, not distance?

Comment: You also ask "what the difference between Equator & Meridians".  The quickest way to understand that is to look at your diagram - the meridians all pass through ***the same points***. (The poles,) The "equators" are totally different, they are like **slices**.  The meridians are all the same length.  The "equators" are all different as you go up and down, see?

Comment: Look up definitions.

Comment: @JoeBlow, circles of constant latitude are called parallels. Only the 0th parallel is called the equator.

Comment: hi @MikeG - sure thing, that's why I said "equators" in quotes.  it's a pedagogic device.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about astronomy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Earth rotates daily about an axis. This axis of rotation intersects the surface of the Earth at the north and south poles. Imagine a plane that is normal to the axis of rotation and lies halfway between the north and south poles. The equator is the intersection of this plane and the surface of the Earth.

Meridians, or lines of longitude, go from pole to pole along a great circle. The Prime Meridian is simply the meridian that we have deemed to be the zero degrees line of longitude. This was an arbitrarily choice. (The French, for example, argued that the Prime Meridian should pass through the Observatory of Paris.)

Imagine going from the south pole to the north pole along the Prime Meridian. The Prime Meridian ends at the north pole. Continuing in the same direction takes you along the 180th degree longitude line. This means that if the Earth was a perfect sphere, the length of the equator would be exactly twice that of the prime meridian.

The Earth isn't a perfect sphere. The Earth's rotation gives the Earth a slight equatorial  bulge. The equator (at sea level) is about 21 km further from the center of the Earth than is the north pole. This means the Earth's equatorial circumference (40075 km) is about 67 kilometers longer than the Earth's meridional circumference (40008 km).

That this is a nice round number is not a coincidence. The original definition of the meter was one ten millionth of the distance at sea level between the equator and the north pole. A prototype metre bar was created based on initial estimates of this distance. It turned out that this initial estimate was a bit off, and by then it was too late to redefine the meter to match these better measurements.